# Webscraping page with login in R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to scrape some webpages of historical newspapers. However, I have to login via my library's website and I am having trouble getting past the login page. I'm using rvest and have replaced the username and password with ****. Many thanks in advance. Here's the code I'm using:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://auth.lse.ac.uk/auth/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fgate.library.lse.ac.uk%2Fidp%2FAuthn%2FRemoteUser"
session <- html_session(url)              
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]

filled_form <- set_values(form,username="****", password="****")

completed_form <- submit_form(session,filled_form)

completed_form %>%
  html_nodes("p") %>%
  html_text()
```

Comment: Have you considered using rselenium? You can program it to work through logins and still scrape at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the following approach :

```
library(RSelenium)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate('https://auth.lse.ac.uk/auth/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fgate.library.lse.ac.uk%2Fidp%2FAuthn%2FRemoteUser')

web_Obj_Username <- remDr$findElement("id", "username")
web_Obj_Username$sendKeysToElement(list("my_user_name"))
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE, useViewer = TRUE) 

web_Obj_Username <- remDr$findElement("id", "password")
web_Obj_Username$sendKeysToElement(list("my_password"))
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE, useViewer = TRUE) 

web_Obj_Button <- remDr$findElement("class name", "button")
web_Obj_Button$clickElement()
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE, useViewer = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider the following approach :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
url <- 'https://auth.lse.ac.uk/auth/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fgate.library.lse.ac.uk%2Fidp%2FAuthn%2FRemoteUser'
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)

web_Obj_Username <- IEApp$Document()$getElementByID("username")
web_Obj_Username$Click()
web_Obj_Username$Focus()
web_Obj_Username[["Value"]] <- "my_user_name"

web_Obj_Username <- IEApp$Document()$getElementByID("password")
web_Obj_Username$Click()
web_Obj_Username$Focus()
web_Obj_Username[["Value"]] <- "my_password"

doc <- IEApp$Document()
clickEvent <- doc$createEvent("MouseEvent")
clickEvent$initEvent("click", TRUE, FALSE)
web_Obj_Login <- IEApp$Document()$getElementsByClassName("button")
web_Obj_Login$item(0)$dispatchEvent(clickEvent)
```